# RABL - How to create a custom child node as collection?

Tags: ruby, json, rabl

```
{     
  total: 250,
  page: 3,
  data: [
        { id: 1, name: "Foo", ...},
        { id: 2, name: "Bar", ...}
  ]
}
```

I want to create structure like this. Value of `id` and `name` are random. It is not saved any variable.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are searching is how to make custom nodes is just with `node` method.When you declare `object` to be `false` you are free to make just custom repsonse.Here is a solution where I generate ids from 1 to 100, and name based on simple conversation to hexademical numbers.

```
object false
node(:total) { |m| @total }
node(:page)  { |m| @page }
node(:data) do |m|
    1.upto(100).map { |id| Hash[[[:id, id], [:name, (id * 143223).to_s(16)]]] }
end
```